# Multiline text when using multiple ternary operators in Template literals

Tags: javascript, template-literals

I want to create multiline text using multiple ternary operators within a single Template literal.

```js
const toolTipText = `${2 * 5 === 10 ? "The value is same" : ""}
  ${"a" === "b" ? "" : "Different letters"}`;

console.log(toolTipText);
```

For example, in the code above, I want `The value is same` in one line & `Different letters` in the next line. However, they are both in the same line. I am basically trying to add lines on text based on conditions.

How to achieve it?

Comment: The site does not allow me to accept the answer within 10mins, hence I was unable to accept. BTW, just on follow-up. Even though the text is a multiline text in JS, it is being rendered as a single line in my browser (React App), I tried `white-space: nowrap;` in CSS but no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try changing the newline character to a `<br>` tag.

Comment: `white-space: pre` might be a better style to apply. It will break lines at `\n` characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `\n` (the escape sequence for a newline character) after `The value is same` in the ternary expression. This way, a new line will only show when there are two different lines that need to be shown:

```js
const toolTipText = `${2 * 5 === 10 ? "The value is same\n" : ""}${"a" === "b" ? "" : "Different letters"}`;
console.log(toolTipText);
```